# Can enemies hear Techies' Proximity Mine warning?

Tags: dota-2

The mines make a beep before they go off and I'd like to know if its something the other team can hear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the enemies can hear the sound. In fact, the sound was added specifically to warn enemies entering the radius of a Proximity Mine, so they have a chance to react and turn around in time.